# fxml getRessource works but getResourceasStream says InputStream is null

Tags: controller, javafx, fxml

i red i this all the posts on getResourceAsStream returning null, but unfortunately none of them works or apply in my case.

I have an fxml file which should be loaded in the Controller class and the Controller should be set in the main class.

```
 public class Main extends Application {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);
private MainFrameController mainFrameController = null;
private BoxService boxService = new BoxServiceImpl();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        /*FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
         fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(null);
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)fxmlLoader.load(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MainFrame.fxml"));*/
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainFrame.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1000,700);


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        //mainFrameController = fxmlLoader.getController();
        //mainFrameController.setBoxService(boxService);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("Application starting...");

    launch(args);
}
```

}

like this it works but i cannot define mainFrameController as the FXMLLoader controller.

my fxml file starts like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="sepm.ss14.e0707713.gui.MainFrameController">
  <children>
    <TabPane layoutX="0.0" layoutY="0.0" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1000.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
      <tabs>
```

and this is my controller

```
public class MainFrameController{

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainFrameController.class);

private BoxService boxService;  
@FXML
private TextField tagessatzFld;
@FXML
private TextField groesseFld;
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> einstreuDd;
@FXML
private RadioButton fensterFld;
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> innenAussenDd;
@FXML
private TextField gebuchtVonFld;
@FXML
private TextField gebuchtBisFld;
ObservableList<Box> boxen;

@FXML
private VBox vbox;

private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-YYYY");

@FXML
public void initialize(){
    boxService = new BoxServiceImpl();
    BoxTableView  tableView = new BoxTableView();
    vbox = tableView.createBoxTableView(boxen);

}


@FXML
private void boxSearch(){
    logger.info("sucheBoxClicked");

    Box b = new Box();

    b.setTagessatz(50.00);
    b.setBoxgroesse(7.00);
    b.setEinstreu("sägespäne");
    b.setFenster(false);
    try {
        b.setGebuchtVon(format.parse("15-01-2014"));
        b.setGebuchtBis(format.parse("28-01-2014"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    b.setInnenAussen("aussen");

    boxen = boxService.search(b);       
}
```

please give me some ideas i'm losing all the faith i will ever finish this project...

1000 Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you try as: AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainFrame.fxml").openStream()); Be sure that the "MainFrame.fxml" file is in the same package as of Main.java

Answer (score 0):

Use Parent node to load the fxml.

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainFrame.fxml"));
```